# Domain of a natural log function

Tags: calculus

I'm a little confused about the domain here:

$$f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \frac1x, \\
g: \mathbb{R} -> \mathbb{R}, g(x) = \ln x.$$
I need the domain/range of the composition.

$f\circ g = \frac{1}{\ln x}$ is undefined since $\ln x$ is undefined if $x \le 0$.

$g\circ f = \ln(\frac1x)$.

Should the domain be all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x > 0$ or $(0,1)$?

The range is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hi @Bob. Don't worry about it now but you might like to know that we prefer [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the domain of $g\circ f$, you need (1) $x$ is in the domain of $f$ and (2) $f(x)$ is in the domain of $g$. The first tells you that $x\in(0,1)$. Since the image of $f$ is $(1,\infty)$ which is always good for $g$, then you're done.

As far as the range, you need to look where $\ln$ sends those inputs you identified above.

Comment: Thanks, then the Domain is $(0,1)$ and the Range is $(- \infty, 0)$.

Comment: @Bob The range would be $(\infty, 0)$ if you weren't doing $f$ first.  But you are. So you need to look at where $f$ sends those values, then what happens with $\ln$.

Comment: Is it $(0, \infty)$ then?

Comment: That is what happens to $(1,\infty)$ under $\ln$, yes.